# Does fossil have a command to link a ticket resolution with a commit?

Tags: fossil

Does the `fossil ticket` command have the option to link a fix for an issue with a specific commit? I need something along the lines of Redmine's option which enables you to link a commit with an issue by the `refs #issueid` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Fossil doesn't have a separate command for this; but if you include the ticket ID between [square brackets] in the commit's description, the commit will automatically be linked to that ticket.

You can view the list of all commits associated with a ticket by clicking the 'Check-ins' menu item on the ticket's page, or directly by opening the `http(s)://`**fossil-root**`/tkttimeline/`**ticket-id**`?y=ci` page.

For example, the following page shows the commits related to the ticket with id `b6eea9446d` of Fossil's own source code repository:

- http://fossil-scm.org/fossil/tkttimeline/b6eea9446d?y=ci

Comment: Redmine has the ability to change a ticket's status if the ticket id is prefixed by a string such as `fixes` or `references`. Doesn't Fossil have this capability?

Comment: @vfclists: no, fossil doesn't automatically change ticket fields. You have to do that using the command line [ticket](http://fossil-scm.org/fossil/help?cmd=ticket) command or the ticket's web page.